# Constant, isset and empty evaluation

Tags: php, variables, undefined, isset

Does anyone know how isset and empty is interpreted by the translator, or how the translator treats undefined variables?

To expand on my question, I have the below code in my include file:

```
define('USER_AUTH', !empty($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['status'])); //user is verified
define('ACC_IS_PENDING', $_SESSION['status'] == '0');//checks to see if user status is pending which has a status of 0
```

USER_AUTH is used as a quick hand to check if user is authenticated. ACC_IS_PENDING is used as a quick hand for when the account status is pending. However, PHP gives me a notice to advise me that $_SESSION['status'] in my second line of code is undefined. I know that it is undefined, but I haven't used it yet! How dare you tell me what I already know. LoL

However, when I trick the code with the below:

```
define('USER_AUTH', !isempty($_SESSION['username']) && !isempty($_SESSION['status']));
define('ACC_IS_PENDING', $_SESSION['status'] == '0');
```

Where isempty() is a custom made function that will always return FALSE. Then no notice!
Alternatively, if I use the below code:

```
define('USER_AUTH', notempty($_SESSION['username']) && notempty($_SESSION['status']));
define('ACC_IS_PENDING', $_SESSION['status'] == '0');
```

Where notempty() always return TRUE, then again no notice.

Am I right in saying that the translator checks that the variable has been tested once, and that if the test resulted in true, then the translator sees this as the variable has been defined?

If this was the case, then what about isset and empty? They both seem to give me notices no matter if the evaluation is true or false.

```
define('USER_AUTH', isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['status']));
define('ACC_IS_PENDING', $_SESSION['status'] == '0');
```

and

```
define('USER_AUTH', empty($_SESSION['username']) && empty($_SESSION['status']));
define('ACC_IS_PENDING', $_SESSION['status'] == '0');
```

Apologies for the long winded question. This seems trivial, but it would be nice to have a quick defined constant without having to get notices! Any help in explanation or a better solution for such trivial task would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention that the custom function is appended with an & to ensure the variable is passed by reference. Like so:
function isempty(&$var){...}

Comment: why not make an IF condition in order to `define` something ? i think you make something too much complicated when its not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP complains because the index 'status' is not defined in the array.  You would need to write

```
!isset($_SESSION['status']) || empty($_SESSION['status']
```

When you "trick" the code as described, PHP will never try to access the non-existing array index, which is why you don't get any notice.

In the fourth code example (with isset), you are still accessing the non-existing array index in the second line of code, so I suspect that's why there's still a notice.

Comment: Actually, the empty() language construct should raise no warning even if the variable does not exists, as per the docs at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php, so the double check with both isset() and empty() should not be needed.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for your input. What you said about tricking the PHP not to look in the non-existing array index rings a bit of a DUH! So I went to do some more testing with my code. Because I was wondering why the first line of code (when tricked) stopped the notice from the second line of code. I got confused.
So when I tricked PHP, it went ahead and defined this variable to be null so the notices never came back to haunt me after I tricked it the first time.
And with the isset and empty function, it should've never worked in this fashion to begin with! Thanks for making me realise this.

Answer (score 1):

a) If you wants to use $_SESSION['status'], you have to check first that the variable is not empty ( see http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php for more details) :

```
if (isset($_SESSION['status'])) {
     // here the value exists and can be used
     Do something...
} else {
     // here the value does not exist and cannot be used
}
```

b) I believe that

```
empty($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['status'])
```

is not constant : it varies from one run to the other.  You may want to use

```
$user_is_logged = empty($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['status']);
```

and use the variable $user_is_logged instead of a constant.  See this section http://www.php.net/manual/fr/language.constants.php for a speek about constants.

Comment: thank you for your input. I got very confused as I thought there was a relationship between the first line of code and the second line of code (see my other comment). When I tricked the first line of code, it stopped the notice from the second line of code. Hence, my confusion. I now know that this has got nothing to do with constant, but rather how PHP interprets my code in a top to bottom fashion. See, I thought that constant was evaluated when it is referenced. But this is not true and gets evaluated as soon as PHP gets to the code. Thnx!

Comment: If you want a constant to be evaluated when written, then I think that a function is a beter deal.